# signum function and derivation

Tags: derivatives

I have these 2 functions: $f_1(x) = |x|^{4}$ and $f_2(x) = |x^{4}|$

Im supposed to find out whether or not these functions derivates are defined in $x = 0$.

I start with $f_1'(x)$ .. If I say $u = |x|$ and $v = u^{4}$

$f_1'(x) = u' * v' = \frac{x}{|x|} * 4x^{3} = 4x^{3} * sgn(x)$

Now I would say $f_1'(0)$ is not defined because it would mean I would have to divide by zero...

And for $f_2'(x)$: If i say $u = x^{4}$ and $v = |u|$

$f_2'(x) = u' * v' = 4x^{3} * \frac{x^{4}}{|x^{4}|} = 4x^{3} * sgn(x^{4})$

And just the same here, $f_2'(0)$ not defined again..

But I'm confused. slightly because of the wikpedia definition of sgn(x) says that sgn(0) = 0.. and my graph drawing program GeoGebra doesnt give "undefined" as answer when plotting 0. But my classmates however, says it's undefined. Now I dont know who to trust, and I dont if there's some magic going on here that I dont understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_1(x)=|x|^4=x^4$ and $f_2(x)=|x^4|=x^4$. Both are the same function and as it is a simple power function it is differentiable for every x.

To check if $f'(x=0)$ is defined calculate $f'(x)=4\cdot x^3$ and check if $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 +(0)}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 -(0)}f'(x)$$